# How to use a grails 3 interceptor only to enforce a form and then resume normal flow of grails app

Tags: spring-security, interceptor, grails-3.0

I have been trying to use the grails 3 interceptor to capture a users email on first login however after capturing the email, the next time they login they are redirected to the email capture form rather than the set home page. I am using spring security if that is relevant information. My code snippet bellow shows what I have done so far. Please advise me if there's an easier way to achieve my goal or what I did wrong.

```
class HomeInterceptor {

public HomeInterceptor() {
    // match all requests except requests
    // to the auth controller
    matchAll().excludes(controller: 'logout')
            .excludes(controller: 'login')
            .excludes(controller: 'home')
            .excludes(controller: 'user', action: 'userProfile')
            .excludes(controller: 'user', action: 'showUserProfile')
}

boolean before() {
    // if the user's email has not been captured,
    // redirect to the user profile

    def springSecurityService = AppHolder.bean(SpringSecurityService)
    def loggedInUser = springSecurityService.currentUser as User

    if (loggedInUser?.email == null){
        flash.message = "Please enter your email before you can proceed"
        redirect(controller: 'user', action: 'userProfile')
        return false
    }else {
        return true
    }
}

boolean after() { true }

void afterView() {
    // no-op
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
import grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator

class HomeInterceptor {

def springSecurityService
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

public HomeInterceptor() {
// match all requests except requests
// to the auth controller
matchAll().excludes(controller: 'logout')
        .excludes(controller: 'login')
        .excludes(controller: 'home')
        .excludes(controller: 'user', action: 'userProfile')
        .excludes(controller: 'user', action: 'showUserProfile')
}

boolean before() {

if (!springSecurityService.principal.email){
    flash.message = "Please enter your email before you can proceed"
    response.sendRedirect("${grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller:'user',action:'userProfile')}")
    return false
}else {
    return true
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful